# ANTLRFileStream is deprecated, what can I use instead?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to compile a test class to test a simple grammer.

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        CharStream input = null;
        // pick an input stream (filename from commandline or stdin)
        if(args.length > 0) input = new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]);
        else input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        // create the lexer
        DrinkLexer lex = new DrinkLexer(input);
        // create a buffer of tokens between the lexer and parser
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        // create the parser, attaching it to the token buffer
        DrinkParser p = new DrinkParser(tokens);
        p.drinkSentence(); // launch parser at drinkSentence file
    }
}
```

How would I go about replacing the deprecated class?

Comment: Clearly it says "as of 4.7 Please use CharStreams interface. "https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRFileStream.html and more can be learned from https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the various static methods from `CharStreams`:

```java
CharStream input = null;
// pick an input stream (filename from commandline or stdin)
if(args.length > 0) input = CharStreams.fromFileName(args[0]);
else input = CharStreams.fromStream(System.in);
// create the lexer
DrinkLexer lex = new DrinkLexer(input);
// create a buffer of tokens between the lexer and parser
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
// create the parser, attaching it to the token buffer
DrinkParser p = new DrinkParser(tokens);
p.drinkSentence(); // launch parser at drinkSentence file
```